# handle popup with selenium python

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I load the browser (selenium python with Chrome) and load the address (example:  http://data.uis.unesco.org/Index.aspx?DataSetCode=EDULIT_DS#). Then I click on 'Country' link text but I can't handle the new window to click on 'Unselect all' or any other configuration. How I can do that?

[image]

Comment: Provide your DOM or url

Comment: dialog window is on a iframe. you will have to switch to it before doing further actions. This is the iframe id  id="DialogFrame"

Comment: http://data.uis.unesco.org/Index.aspx?DataSetCode=EDULIT_DS#